# Program to find numbers with odd no of divisors

Tags: c, optimization

Given 2 integers L and R, you are expected to find the number of integers between L and R that have odd number of divisors.

Input Format :

First line contains a single integer T
, the number of test cases. Each of the next T lines contains two space separated integers Li and Ri, depicting the parameters of the ith test case.

Constraints

1≤ T ≤ 10000

1≤ L ≤ R ≤ 10^18

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int t;
    long int cnt,countj;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    long long int l[t], r[t];
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<t;i++){
        scanf("%d%d",&l[i],&r[i]);
        }

    int div[t];
    for(i=0;i<t;i++){
        //count[i]=0;
        cnt=0;
        for(int j=l[i]+1;j<r[i];j++){
            countj=0;
            for(int k=1;k<=j/2;k++){
                if(j%k==0)
                   countj++;
            }
            if ((countj%2)==0)
            cnt++;
        }
        printf("%ld\n",cnt);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This program takes too long to execute, especially for bigger numbers, how can it be optimized ?
And it doesent pass all the test cases, what may be error in the code?

Comment: how long is too long? how big is bigger?

Comment: *all* divisors, or only the prime divisors ?

Comment: Constraints

1 ≤ T ≤ 10000

1 ≤ L ≤ R ≤ 10^18   @user3528438

Comment: I was thinking about factorizing the number into prime divisors and count them, if any of the prime divisors has a odd count then it will have even number of divisors (if you include 1 and the number itself). But still that requires factorizing all numbers between L and R and still too expensive for a problem size of 10^18.

Comment: All divisors, but the number of divisors must be odd , not the value of the divisor. @wildplasser

Comment: But how would you know if a number is a perfect square? To check if it is a perfect square or not, for  a problem size of 10^18, would itself be a very costly operation.. @WhozCraig

Comment: Only integers that are perfect squares (1,4,9,16, etc..) have an odd number of divisors. I would think that with some creative use of std::sqrt would simplify this considerably, don't you think? Consider this: All divisors of an integer X come in pairs. If X has divisor Y, then there must be a Z such that ZY=X. A perfect square has solo divisor W, where WW=X, and thus the odd-man-out. So if the question is : "You are expected to find the number of integers between L and R that have odd number of divisors.", it's really, "Find the number of perfect squares between L and R."

Comment: @MayankThakur Take the square root, cast to a suitably large integer type, multiply, if it is the number you started with, it's perfect. Regarding cost, if you think *factoring* a number of that magnitude is faster than calculating its square root, think again.

Comment: @WhozCraig so basically x = floor(sqrt(r)) - ceil(sqrt(l)) + 1?

Comment: Just for fun and probably speed optimisation, I think you only need to search for the first square "NN" in the range. The next square is NN+2N+1. Check wether it is still in the range. Repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is indeed as you described, there a *many* ways you can improve performance, just one of them being below, but you have to understand the theory behind what you're trying to accomplish first.

Integers with odd numbers of divisors are always *perfect squares*. Given some number `N`, if `X` is a divisor there must be some corresponding `Y` such that `XY=N` holds true. They always come in pairs. The exception is a *perfect square*. In that case they number has some divisor `W` such that `WW=N`, and `W` is only counted as *one* divisor. Therefore `N` has an *odd* number of divisors.

So how does this help? Well, your stated task is to find all integers from `L` through `R` having an odd count of divisors. But we just showed that only perfect squares have such a property. Therefore, what that question is really asking is:

> Find the number of perfect squares between two integers `L` and `R`.

One such algorithm is simply this:

- Starting with `L` take the floating point square root of the test number
- Square the root after converting to an appropriate integer type
- If the square of the root results in the original number, you have a perfect square. Stop looping.
- Otherwise, increment you test number and try again. Stop if you pass `R` or find a perfect square, whichever comes *first*.

If you found no perfect square, the answer is zero and you're done. If you found a perfect square, you will no longer need to loop incrementally across `L` and `R`. You have a starting point (a perfect root), and now you will loop by incrementally increasing that root until its square *exceeds* `R`. This will *significantly* reduce the number of iterations.

In the below code:

- `T`  : the number of tests
- `L`  : the first number in a test series
- `R`  : the last number in a test series
- `N`  : the number of odd-divisor values between `L` and `R` *inclusive*
- `sr` : The running square-root of our discovery loops.

**Code**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int T = 0;
    if (scanf("%u", &T) != 1)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    while (T--)
    {
        unsigned int L, R, N=0, sr, i;
        if (scanf("%u %u", &L, &R) != 2)
            return EXIT_FAILURE;

        for (i=L; i<=R; ++i)
        {
            sr = sqrt(i);
            if (sr * sr == i)
                break;
        }

        if (i <= R)
            for (;sr*sr <= R; ++sr,++N);

        printf("%u\n", N);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
5 
1 2 
10 100
100 1000
500 2500
1 262144
```

**Output**

```
1
7
22
28
512
```

**Performance**

This code performs well], considering how little of it there is. The resulting disassembly using clang 3.9.1 with `-x c -O2` is respectable.

```
.LC0:
        .string "%u"
.LC1:
        .string "%u %u"
.LC3:
        .string "%u\n"
main:
        push    rbp
        push    rbx
        xor     eax, eax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     ebp, 1
        sub     rsp, 40
        lea     rsi, [rsp+20]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+20], 0
        call    __isoc99_scanf
        cmp     eax, 1
        je      .L24
.L1:
        add     rsp, 40
        mov     eax, ebp
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        ret
.L24:
        mov     ebp, eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp+20]
        lea     edx, [rax-1]
        test    eax, eax
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+20], edx
        je      .L25
.L3:
        lea     rdx, [rsp+28]
        lea     rsi, [rsp+24]
        xor     eax, eax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        call    __isoc99_scanf
        cmp     eax, 2
        jne     .L1
        mov     ebx, DWORD PTR [rsp+24]
        cmp     ebx, DWORD PTR [rsp+28]
        jbe     .L10
        jmp     .L11
.L26:
        add     ebx, 1
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rsp+28], ebx
        jb      .L11
.L10:
        pxor    xmm0, xmm0
        mov     eax, ebx
        pxor    xmm2, xmm2
        cvtsi2sdq       xmm0, rax
        ucomisd xmm2, xmm0
        sqrtsd  xmm1, xmm0
        jbe     .L8
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rsp+8], xmm1
        call    sqrt
        movsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rsp+8]
.L8:
        cvttsd2si       rax, xmm1
        mov     edx, eax
        mov     ecx, eax
        imul    edx, eax
        cmp     edx, ebx
        jne     .L26
        mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rsp+28]
        cmp     ebx, edi
        ja      .L11
.L12:
        add     eax, 1
        mov     edx, eax
        mov     esi, eax
        imul    edx, eax
        sub     esi, ecx
        cmp     edi, edx
        jnb     .L12
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC3
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
.L27:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp+20]
        lea     edx, [rax-1]
        test    eax, eax
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+20], edx
        jne     .L3
.L25:
        xor     ebp, ebp
        jmp     .L1
.L11:
        xor     esi, esi
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC3
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        jmp     .L27
```

That's it. It could be made even faster, but so long as it meets your performance needs, it probably isn't worth more effort (so I hope it does) Normally questions about odd-divisors also request the one number with the lowest (or highest) *number of divisors*, which make it much more complicated. The question you stated does not ask that, and thus the problem reduces down very well.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that you want to count the numbers that have odd numbers of divisors, but you are counting, the even ones.

Comment: If you observe carefully, I am iterating through the loop till j<=k/2 and not till k,. So if it has odd no of divisors, till half, it'd have even no of divisors. Eg. div(4)= { 1, 2,4}
So, till 2, it has only {1,2} which are even in number.
So this is not a problem.
@BlazeChill